# Disable TRACE an OPTIONS in NGINX-ingress with snippets

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

A security probe recently recommended disabling the TRACE and OPTIONS methods for my K8s nginx-ingress.  I've been googling for a few days but not gotten anywhere, the searches are a bit vague.  I think for the TRACE option I have:

```
    config:
      entries:
        server-snippets: |
          opentracing off;
```

But this is a bit of guessing, and I haven't found anything concrete.  Also, is there a way to turn off the OS/Fingerprinting options in the same or similar blocks for consistency?

Suggestions/help?